# Is there any way to automatically create a constructor for python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class `C` like the following, and I can't construct it like `C("a", 1, 2.5)`.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = ""
        self.B = 0
        self.C = 1.2
```

So I write the following function `make_c`.

```
def make_c(a, b, c):
    c = C()
    c.A = a
    c.B = b
    c.C = c
```

However, this is not neat, and I have to create differenct versions of `make_CLS` for every `CLS`. So I am wondering if there are some ways that I do not need to write `make_c`.

Maybe the following code works, but I don't know if it is the best way, since `exec` is needed, and I still have to name all fields.

```
def make_common(cls_name, fields_map):
    o = eval(cls_name)
    for k,v in fields_map.iteritems():
        exec "o.{}={}".format(k, v)
    return o
```

This question is under Python2, however, if there are better ways only in Python3, I am also willing to know that.

**--EDIT--**

I can not alter definition of class `C`, because there codes are all generated by some other programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this? this avoids using eval

```
def make_class(cls_name, fields):
    my_class = globals()[cls_name]()
    my_class.__dict__.update(fields)
    return my_class
```

Then

```
my_class = make_class('C', {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. However, is there anyway to replace `cls_name`? So I can write something like `make_class(C, {...})` rather than `make_class("C", {...})`?

Comment: In that case just use `my_class = cls_name()`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the variables you want to pass to your `__init__()` function?

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self,a , b, c):
        self.A = a
        self.B = b
        self.C = c

test = C("a", 1, 2.5)

test.A
#'a'
```

Comment: Ok, I should put that in my question, this is because all codes are generated by some other programs and I find no way to alter that

Comment: So are you saying. `C()` exists in another program, which you do not have access to? And you want to return objects for `C()` without modifying the code written under `C()`?

Comment: I have access to `C`, but I can't modify codes of `C` because `C` is generated by another program.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. The code itself is generated by another program? The values of `a,b, c`?